# automated change in panel color based on user rating

Tags: html, css, jsp, panel

I am working on a website in which users can complaint about a problem, and accordingly others suggest, reply etc. What i want is that each user suggestion based on its rating should have different color panel like if rating is 3 then  blue , if it is 4 then somewhat darker, and so on..can anyone suggest a way..? considering i am new to html and webdesign.

**User ratings**

```
1-3 => BLUE
4-6 => DARK BLUE
7-10 => NAVY BLUE
```

which language can meet the above requirements.?

Comment: Which language are you using to collect and display the ratings?

Comment: @Pekka i have to use JSP. with jQuery and AJAX

Comment: @Pekka can you tell me the way in some other language like PHP, because logic will be same..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use CSS for this. Specify a classname for each of those values. E.g.

```css
.rating-1, .rating-2, .rating-3 {
    background: blue;
}

.rating-4, .rating-5, .rating-6 {
    background: darkblue;
}

.rating-7, .rating-8, .rating-9, .rating-10 {
    background: navy;
}
```

Then let JSP dynamically generate the desired CSS classname on the HTML element of interest. E.g.

```html
<div class="rating-${rating.score}">${rating.score}</div>
```

#### See also:

- [CSS Beginner Tutorial](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssbeginner/)